# Problem with Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android studio and i tried downgrading in the build gradle and i have tried everything for this issue and nothing works please help me!

I always get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process 
Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: This issue has been solved in Google services dependencies. Just add this line `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` to project level `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is due to the fact that you did not initialize the instance of FirebaseApp.
By the time the firebase methods are called, you must initialize it:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());
```

You can insert it in begin of onCreate() in Activity (before calling method of Firebase!).

Or you can insert it in onCreate() of class (if exists) which extends Application class.

If you do not have a class that extends Application, then you must create it:

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

public class MyApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
}
}
```

After this add name in Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    ...
</application>
```

**If that doesn't help** - then downgrade/upgrade the dependency version of com.google.gms.google-services to stable version 4.3.8

Comment: @AndroidDev Edit please code of register class with changes which you done.
Do you have a class which extends Application? Look please my edited answer

Comment: @AndroidDev can you attach full stacktrace of error?

Comment: @AndroidDev Exception occurs in the Base_Activity class. 
Add FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext()) in onCreate() before FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

Comment: @AndroidDev Edit Base_Activity with changes and attach again full stacktrace

Comment: @AndroidDev This issue may be due to the version of com.google.gms.google-services. Try change version of dependency from 4.3.9 to 4.3.8 in gradle level-project and run again.

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks so much for your time and for your patience

Comment: @AndroidDev Happy to help. Please confirm the answer